# SQL Server 2008 VarChar To DateTime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table where unfortunately a number of dates are stored as strings.

I have a number of reports that cast them to datetimes and filter by them. This was working fine until today when all of a sudden i'm getting this error

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

The dates are all stored in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd" and are all valid.

If I run the following SQL statement

```
SELECT CAST('2010-06-02' AS DateTime)
```

I would expect to get "2010-06-02" however as of today I'm getting "2010-02-06" something has changed with the way SQL formats dates. I've had a look in regional settings on the server and it all looks to be correct.

What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unambiguous way of getting this conversion is to do the following:

```
SELECT CAST(replace('2010-06-02', '-', '') AS DateTime)
```

And that will always be interpreted as YYYYMMDD, ignoring the `set dateformat ydm` declaration or any cultural settings that the database has.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the format explicitly

```
select convert(datetime, '2010-06-02',101)
```

Comment: @Gavin - it could be that the Language has been changed on the Database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191448.aspx

Comment: @Gavin - some further info on Date and Time in SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx

Comment: @Gavin Draper That impression was close to the real thing. It's the date string without hyphens that gets interpreted ignoring any culture settings that you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: What else could be causing this?

The local, You probably are under the local101(US) and put data from 103 (British/French)

Like barry sad use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)